Are there any programs where I can fit curves to a set of data points manually?
I would like to know of any software out there that just lets me fit curves, lines or other functions to a set of data points manually.
I.e. rather than having to write code, ideally I'd like to be able to drag and drop from a menu of possible template functions, and then I would be allowed to stretch and morph the function using my computer mouse, until the curve/line more or less fits the data points.
